# How do you make less show the filename?

Tags: less

I often have multiple terminal windows opened with less (eg comparing various log files). I forget which file is which. Is there a similar command to ^G in vi which displays the name of the file currently being viewed?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Compatible: `^G`. Easy to type: `=`. Less copied several key bindings from vi, including this one. This displays the file name (the path that you passed on the `less` command line) and the position in the file.

You can have this information permanently by calling `less` with the `-M` option. Include `-M` in the `LESS` environment variable. You can set this variable in your `~/.profile`, `~/.pam_environment` or wherever you define environment variables. Alternatively, you can set `LESS` by using [`lesskey`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lesskey) to produce the configuration file  `~/.less` which is read by `less`.

Comment: Note that if you use `less +F -M <filename>` it won't show the filename until you quit the follow. (`+F` = `--follow-name`)

Comment: Awesome answer — I did not know about `lesskey` or about the `-M` option!

Answer (score 4):

I just found -M (show more verbose status line), which seems to do what I want.